# error in JenaParser code

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I want run this code:

```
public class JenaParser {

public static void main(String[] args){
    String pathFolder="E:/swetodblp_april_2008.rdf"; 
    File folder=new File(pathFolder);
    File[] files=folder.listFiles();
    for(File file:files){
        try {
            System.out.println("*** File: name="+file.getName()+" path="+file.getPath());

            InputStream in=null;
            in = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());

            OutputStream output=null;
            output = new FileOutputStream(pathFolder+"/"+ file.getName() +".nt");

            Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
            RDFDataMgr.read(model, in, org.apache.jena.riot.Lang.RDFXML);
            RDFDataMgr.write(output, model, org.apache.jena.riot.RDFFormat.NTRIPLES_ASCII) ;

            //Extratct URIs
            ArrayList outgoingUrls = new ArrayList();
            for (StmtIterator i = model.listStatements(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                Statement s = (Statement) i.next();
                if (!s.getSubject().isAnon()) {
                    outgoingUrls.add( s.getSubject().getURI());
                }
                outgoingUrls.add( s.getPredicate().getURI() );
                if (s.getObject().isResource() && !s.getResource().isAnon()) {
                    outgoingUrls.add( s.getResource().getURI() );
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}
}}
```

when run show this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenaparser.JenaParser.main(JenaParser.java:32)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Which is the line 32 in your code?

Comment: Why are you setting your variables to null and then immediately changing their values? Just use `InputStream in = new FileInputStream(...);` etc.

Comment: Dear  Pradeep Simha, this line in my code:   for(File file:files)

Comment: Dear Jon Skeet, I change my code from: InputStream in=null;
                in = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());  to:    InputStream in=new FileInputStream(file.getPath());                       And out too, but show this error!

Answer (score 1):

I expect that `E:/swetodblp_april_2008.rdf` is the path to a single file, not to a directory.  Note that `listFiles` returns `null` if the File is not a directory:

> ### [listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)
>
> ```
> public File[] listFiles()
> ```
>
> Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. …
>
> #### Returns
>
> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

What I expect is happening, then, is this:

```
String pathFolder="E:/swetodblp_april_2008.rdf";
```

`pathFolder` is a string that is the pathname of an RDF document (but not of a directory).

```
File folder=new File(pathFolder);
```

The file `folder` is created successfully, but it denotes a regular file, not a directory.

```
File[] files=folder.listFiles();
```

The call `folder.listFiles()` returns without throwing an exception, but because the file is not a directory, it returns `null`.  This means that you get a null pointer exception when you try to iterate over the array (because there is no array) in

```
for( File file : files ) {
  …
}
```

If you're trying to iterate over all the files in the same directory as `E:/swetodblp_april_2008.rdf`, then you could do something like:

```
String pathFolder="E:/swetodblp_april_2008.rdf"; 
File folder=new File(pathFolder);
File[] files=folder.getParentFile().listFiles(); // note getParentFile()
```

If you're just trying to iterate over files in `E:/`, then you could simply do:

```
String pathFolder="E:/"; 
File folder=new File(pathFolder);
File[] files=folder.listFiles();
```